# Why my $http is not working?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating an app and a need put outside and array using `json` data but doesn't work. In www folder I create a folder to put all my `json` data files. I'm new in this thing.

```
.controller('cafeteriaCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, produtoService, $http) {

 $http.get('appdata/cafes.json').success(function (data) {
        // The json data will now be in scope.
        $scope.items = data;
    });
})
```

**json file**:

```
[ 
    {
        nome: "Cafe Expresso", 
        preco: 1.00, 
        subtotal: 1.00, 
        qntd: 1, like: 0, 
        descricao: "O mais delicioso e fresco cafe para voce começar sua manhã, ou dar aquela energia para o resto do seu dia", 
        img:'img/cafe_1.jpg'
    },
    {
        nome: "Cafe com leite", 
        preco: 1.20, 
        subtotal: 1.20, 
        qntd: 1, 
        like: 0, 
        descricao: "Do mais delicioso cafe fresco moido na hora não tem como não adicionar leite para ficar mais muito mais delicioso", 
        img: 'img/cafe_2.jpg'
    }
]
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: just not work, im getting nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is in a **bad format** and it will make your `$http` request fail. You can [validate your json here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Change your json like this (Ex. Use `"img/cafe_1.jpg"` instead of `'img/cafe_1.jpg'`)

```
{ 
    "cafe1": {
        "nome": "Cafe Expresso", 
        "preco": 1.00, 
        "subtotal": 1.00, 
        "qntd": 1, "like": 0, 
        "descricao": "O mais delicioso e fresco cafe para voce começar sua manhã, ou dar aquela energia para o resto do seu dia", 
        "img":"img/cafe_1.jpg"
    },
    "cafe2": {
        "nome": "Cafe com leite", 
        "preco": 1.20, 
        "subtotal": 1.20, 
        "qntd": 1, 
        "like": 0, 
        "descricao": "Do mais delicioso cafe fresco moido na hora não tem como não adicionar leite para ficar mais muito mais delicioso", 
        "img": "img/cafe_2.jpg"
    }
}
```